# Renormalization scheme dependence

Tags: quantum-field-theory, field-theory, renormalization

Is it possible that the QFTs at hand show dependence on the renormalization point at which renormalization conditions are introduced?

Comment: Which qft’s are “at hand”? Do you mean the standard model specifically?

Comment: no. I am talking about any qft in general. Is there any example of a qft which could have dependence on the renormalization point chosen??? particularly for dynamic interaction.

Comment: To clarify further, QFTs in general depend on the renormalization scheme and scale (e.g. the value of the fine structure constant runs with the cutoff). But predictions of physical observables should not depend on the arbitrary scheme and scale. In some cases, the cutoff may have some physical meaning such as a lattice spacing in a crystal, in which case observables might depend on it. Is this close to what you have in mind?